# No margin between header toolbar and content on Android preview Ionic Framework VueJs 3

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic7

i have some issue with margin between header toolbar and content.
on iphone preview i just got perfect margin but when i switch to android, theres no gap between them. the header ovveride the content.
is my code wrong?

[image: this is my content code]

[image: toolbar code]

[image: Ios preview]

[image: Android preview]

ive try to add ion-padding/ion-margin class in any tag like template/page or card its change the gap but why thers difference between ios and android where in android i have to add empty card just to adding the gap.  and if i do that, in ios will be long gap

Comment: You can add conditional class on your `ion-content` tag. For example: `<ion-content :class="{'ion-padding-top' : platform == 'android'}">`. it will add padding at top only on android platform. The result you are getting currently is default behaviour.